# Backspace stop working on my Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Backspace just suddenly stop working on VS Code. I have reset VS Code by going to JSON file and also reset the system keyboard to a default.

Comment: Do you have a spare keyboard to try to exclude it being a hardware issue?

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

This method is working at 100%. Go to "File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts" and search for deleteLeft and add keybinding "Backspace".